# Angular2 show/hide dropdown in ngFor, and hide when clicked anywhere else?

Tags: html, css, angular, drop-down-menu, toggle

I know this question has been probably asked thousand of times, but I couldn't find any correct solution for angular2.

So I have a table and I'm setting data for each row that I'm getting from a server. Hence I have an `ngFor`:

```js
<table class="table table-hover mb-0 hidden-sm-down table-curved">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let module of modules; let index = index" #moduleObject >
      <td class="text-center"><md-checkbox></md-checkbox></td>
        <td>
          <a class="test" (click)="module._clicked = !module._clicked"></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu table-dropdown" role="menu" [ngClass]="{'table-dropdown-open' : module._clicked}">
            <li><a (click)="_showDialogue =! _showDialogue; _getModuleCode(module)">Edit Module</a></li>
            <li><a (click)="removeModule(module.Code)" >Remove Module</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So each row will look like this:
[image]

And I have a toggle function that when you click on the 3 dots, it shows a dropdown box, like so:

[image]

But the toggle function has two issues which I honestly have no Idea how to fix:

1 - When you click on the 3 dots, it works for the first two clicks, and after that when you click on another row's 3 dots it won't work (meaning you have to double click in order to show the dropdown.

2 - Currently my toggle effect is only happening when I have to click on the 3 dots, but I want to achieve that when the user clicks on another rows' 3 dots, the drop down thats shown anywhere else hides. And when the user clicks anywhere else, it also hides the rest dropdown.

The 2nd was tough for me, so I have a very inefficient way of hiding the dropdown.

```js
CloseAllDropDown() {
  //console.log(a)
  var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0].querySelectorAll('ul');
  for (let i = 0; i < dropdown.length; ++i) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('table-dropdown-open')[0].classList.remove('tabl‌​e-dropdown-open');
  }
}
```

How Can I achieve the two lists above?

## Update

```js
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let module of modules; let index = index" #moduleObject >
    <td class="text-center"><md-checkbox></md-checkbox></td>
    <td (clickOutside)="visible = false">
      <a class="test" (click)="module._clicked = !module._clicked"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu table-dropdown" role="menu" [ngClass]="{ 'table-dropdown-open' : module._clicked }" >
        <li><a (click)="_showDialogue =! _showDialogue; _getModuleCode(module)">Edit Module</a></li>
        <li><a (click)="removeModule(module.Code)" >Remove Module</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: The problem is that you are using `return` inside of a loop. As soon as either condition is met for the first time, the function will 'end' without the loop checking against any subsequent <ul>s. To close **all** dropdowns from a single element, you would need to use another `querySelectorAll` inside the for loop -- you shouldn't need an `if` conditional at all by the sound of it :)

Comment: Hmm could you please abbreviate more on your point. And also how would I resolve my 1st option? @ObsidianAge

Comment: It **sounds** like you need something like: `document.getElementsByClassName('table-dropdown-open')[0].classList.remove('table-dropdown-open');`. That should remove the class for each element whenever `CloseAllDropDown` is called. The 1st point **should** be resolved by simply not using `return` in a loop.

Comment: I see where your going with this. But that still wont resolve the 1st point because the first point says that when I click on specific 3 dots, only that dropdown shows, and the rest hides. @ObsidianAge

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer any idea mate? I've seen you answering most angular questions on SO. Your help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
     selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
   constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

@Output()
public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
    if (!targetElement) {
        return;
    }

    const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!clickedInside) {
        this.clickOutside.emit(event);
    }
}}
```

And then you can call it where you want. For the example:

```
<div (clickOutside)="visible = false"</div>
```

Comment: Is this for when you click anywhere else and hides the dropdown box? Where dould I give this condition `(clickOutside)="visible = false"`? In my click event?

Comment: Shall I remove the `(click)` event from my `a` tag

Comment: Yes. Put it on the second td. No, leave (click) on a.

Comment: Ive added the recent code above. Please check under update section. It doesnt work for me.

Comment: I've just posted 'visible' variable as example. You have to change it to one you use and that is - module._clicked. So you have to do (clickOutside)="module._clicked = false"

Comment: Yes I tried both actually, but it didnt work. It seems that the OnClick method inside the directive is not being used anywhere.

Comment: Have you imported ClickOutsideDirective into your NgModule?

Comment: Honestly, I completely forgot. Hang on there bud, will od that now

Comment: Ok, so Ive imported it in my declaration array in ngModule. But the onClick method inside it has still no usage.

Comment: Please add plunker so I can help you.

Comment: Im sorry I don't know how to create a plunker, and this problem is based on a very complex application which of course is unnecessary to show in plunker. Perhaps if you can show how your directive is acting in plunker, it would be appreciate it, otherwise I would really appreciate if you could assist just a little longer.

Comment: I think we need to be calling `onClick()` method somewhere, perhaps in my `(click)` for `a` ?

Comment: I wolud like to help you but I can't without code. I'm using the same functionality and it works for me.

Comment: Could you please post your code that works? If that's not too much to ask? Apologies

Comment: I was busy trying to implement your code and it worked finally. Really appreciate it mate